# How to make materialize slider fullscreen on the top page only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, materialize

I have the default code of slider on MaterializeCSS, I know I can just add fullscreen on slider class but when I do that my other content gets hidden inside my slider.

Is it possible to add fullscreen on slider only on top of the page and still make the slider interact with other content of my page normally?

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
            <div class="caption center-align">
                <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
                <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2"> <!-- random image -->
            <div class="caption left-align">
                <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
                <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3"> <!-- random image -->
            <div class="caption right-align">
                <h3>Right Aligned Caption</h3>
                <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4"> <!-- random image -->
            <div class="caption center-align">
                <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
                <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Make sure the slider is not positioned absolute..

I think you should share you css as well.